# how to make container widht 960px -fixed on bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, twitter-bootstrap-3, containers

I want to make. container with width 960px and the middle position, but I can not make it in bootstrap3

I've tried to change it manually. container {width: 960px} .. but instead makes it strange when I resize

please help me.

Comment: Post your code so that we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that Bootstrap 3 is a mobile first framework. In order to change the container size, you must change it for all 3 three breakpoints that are set. Try using the following (after changing with your desired values):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

For those using LESS and compiling their own css, these can be found/adjusted variables.less.